# MIPS, unexpected (lack-of) result from add.s

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, ieee-754

After running the following code on MIPS I would expect $f0 to contain 0x7f800001 but it remains 0x7f800000 am I misunderstanding how floats work? Do I need to use double precision in this case? I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why this isn't giving the result I'm expecting and how I can get the expected result.

```
li $t0, 0x7f800000
mtc1 $t0, $f0

li $t1, 1
mtc1 $t1, $f1

add.s $f0, $f0, $f1
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized my misunderstanding was in assuming the binary representation of floating point numbers was the same as integers (words) which is not the case.

To make this work as expected (but still not contain 0x7f80001 as floats are represented differently from integers) I had to convert the values from a word to a float using:

```
  cvt.s.w $f0, $f0
  cvt.s.w $f1, $f1
```

Comment: you can also use .float 1.0 to declare data that is directly in floating point format, then use l.s to load such into float registers.

Comment: Thanks, yeah sorry this is just a code snippet for me to understand why some other system wasn't working. In this case I wasn't able to do that but still useful info... first time working with floats in mips and I didn't think to convert.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format details how bit-patterns represent values in the IEEE754 binary32 format.  https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html is a very nice decimal <-> float converter that shows checkboxes for each bit, and decodes the meaning of mantissa, exponent, and sign, and stuff like that.

Comment: Note that if you converted back from float to integer, you *would* get 0x7f80001 (unless that addition has rounding error).  As you probably realized, your assumption doesn't hold up as soon as you state it explicitly in words like that; floating point needs to be able to represent fractional values as well (that's the whole point), but every integer bit pattern represents an integer.  A binary32 bit pattern of `1` represents the smallest positive subnormal value; the smallest float above `0.0`.  This is smaller than float epsilon so adding it to `1.0` would lose it to rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

`0x7f800000` represents single-precision +INF.  Adding any value, other than NaN or a negative number(?), to that will yield +INF.

`0x7f800001` is one of many representations of NaN.